# Question on projective module

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module

Let $R$ be a ring an $M$ be a projective $R$-module. Show that there exists a free $R$-module $F$ such that
$$M\oplus F\cong F.$$

Any hints?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Mazur_swindle#Eilenberg_swindle

Comment: why is the Eilensberg swindle is okay to use here?